# Updating Schedules programmatically table-based Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

In one of my Java projects with jdbc-based Quartz scheduler I am in need to update the schedule of a preconfigured job frequently. i.e. using the JobID as the handle I would like to update the schedule in the tables. Is this possible?

Comment: What version of Quartz are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend this approach, I think it's better to reSchedule job using the method dedicated to this in QuartzScheduler object.

Look at rescheduleJob in:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html