# how to update a schedule in the next request in quartz

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am trying to using quartz in my program. I need to update the schedule of the job.

After I read the sample code by Google and read docs [2-2-1_Quartz_Scheduler_Example_Programs_and_Sample_Code.pdf](https://documentation.softwareag.com/terracotta/quartz_221/2-2-1_Quartz_Scheduler_Example_Programs_and_Sample_Code.pdf).

I know that there are several steps to schedule a job with certain time:

1. Create a job. The job can be identified by job name, group, jobkey.
2. Create a trigger for that job with specific time. The trigger also can be identified by name, group triggerkey. A job can have multiple triggers.
3. Create the schedule to the job and the trigger.

Well, how to identify the schedule? If you already get the scheduler, you can [list jobs](https://www.w3schools.blog/quartz-listing-all-jobs-example).

```java
            for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
                 for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(
                     GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {      
              String jobName = jobKey.getName();
              String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();
 
              List triggers = (List) 
                      scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
              Date nextFireTime = triggers.get(0).getNextFireTime();
              System.out.println("Job : " + jobName + ", Group : "
                    + jobGroup + ", Next execution time : "
                        + nextFireTime); 
          }
```

You also get can get triggers by `schedule.getTriggers()`.

Well, Imagine that when the user requests my service for the first time. I create the job with jobkey as ("jobname", "jobgroup") with trigger and assign them into a schedule. If the user requests my service again trying to update the trigger time, how do I find the scheduler by ("jobname", "jobgroup")? How do I identity the schedule, so that I can find the scheduler when the user's next request coming in?

Although I can reschedule my job with scheduler:

```java
#How-To: Update a Trigger


#Replacing a Trigger


// Define a new Trigger
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
 .withIdentity("newTrigger", "group1")
 .startNow()
 .build();
// tell the scheduler to remove the old trigger with the given key, and
// put the new one in its place
sched.rescheduleJob(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1"), trigger);


#Updating an Existing Trigger
// retrieve the trigger
Trigger oldTrigger = sched.getTrigger(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1");
// obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();
// update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
// (other builder methods could be called, to change the trigger in any
// desired way)
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
 .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
 .withRepeatCount(10)
 .build();
sched.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
```

Again, how do I find the scheduler? How do I identity the scheduler? How to update a schedule in the next request in quartz?

Is it the similar article? [updating-schedules-programmatically-table-based-quartz-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932934/updating-schedules-programmatically-table-based-quartz-scheduler) But it is not the solution.